# Issues with jQuery UI tabs, AJAX and Ajaxpager

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have searched through a lot of the similar questions on here, and tried many things but I am still stuck. Not that I am relatively new to jQuery.

What I want to do is use jQuery UI tabs (with jQuery address - for back button and bookmarking). I have this working no problem.

Inside each tab, I am trying to use an jQuery UI ajaxpager.  I am having a problem getting the pager to initiate inside the ajax loaded content. Correction: used `ajaxComplete` the get the pager initialized on the second tab..

Now my problem is this.

- load page. OK
- click tab 2. OK
- click tab 1. OK

now that I'm back on tab 1, tab 2 will not work.

I am sure it is something simple. You can view my demo here: http://www.sjlarchitect.com/help/projects_en1.html

I have been struggling for a couple days now trying to get this implemented. I am sure it is something very simple. If it's not ok to post a link to my example please advise me.

Note: pager is not styled, etc. etc. just trying to get the implementation to work.

Comment: I just tried your demo and it worked fine. I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 9.04. What browser did you try it in?

Comment: works for me as well, on Mac with Safari 4.0.3...

Comment: I am using FF 3.0.14.

I updated the text on the pages so you know where you are. click thorough tab2, tab1, tab2.... This third click on tab 2 will not work for me. Also does not work for me ie.

If anyone know a better way of accomlpishing jquery ui ajax tabs, with back button and bookmarking support, and an ajax pager, I am open to changing my solution.

Comment: should have specified in ie 6

Comment: It appears that once the tab is clicked once, it will no longer load the content when clicked again.

Comment: 5 hours later and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with the UI dialog box.  I had to add an onLoadComplete logic and then onUnload logic to destroy the data.  I believe this is because when you switch tabs its actually re-init-ing the jquery constructors, so when you switch, you will need to de initialize the information you have in there, in this case, jquery ui ajaxpager.

I will take a look and see if I can come up with a more definite answer, but that is my best guess without diving into the code.

Comment: OK that would be great. I am sure it something very easy I am overlooking. I have no problems using either (tabs and pager) on there own, but when I put the on the same page I can't get through the click sequence I posted above.

Comment: Could you send a zip of the files that arn't working?  Maybe I can take a look at your exact setup.  I checked the link above, but it wasn't working...